# Problems with connecting to ASM instance

Tags: linux, oracle-11g

I have Oracle11 with RAC installed on RedHat 5.
I have two servers with two instances one on each one.
In each server I succeed connect to appropriate instance of database but not to instance of ASM.

I connect with user oracle11 and type:
export ORACLE_SID=+ASM1
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
It connects but write:
Connected to an idle instance
and when I try to access to parameters or views I have errors.

For know that +ASM1 is the SID I type:
ps aux | grep pmon
and get:
asm_pmon_+ASM1

I tried also with +ASM but it was also unsuccessfully.

What is wrong here?

Comment: To the point I set also ORCLE_HOME of ASM. The value I get from /etc/oratab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won!!! the solution is to set ORACLE_HOME of ASM's instance home directory without / at the end. Here I get answer: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/m/459515/153291/#msg_459515